# Calculator in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, calculator

I have been trying to build a simple calculator in android studio.I am a beginner and have only basic knowledge of java.I am trying to accept values in a single text field instead of using two different text field.I have used a on click listener on my operator buttons and inside that on the equals button.But my application closes as soon as i click on the operator buttons.How can i use a single text view two accept two numbers or more and apply a mathematical operator on them?

edit:as I have already stated I have very little knowledge of java.I did a google search before posting this question.

```
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            n.setText("");
            final float a = Float.parseFloat(n.getText().toString());
            n.setText("");
            equals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    float b = Float.parseFloat(n.getText().toString());
                    float c = a + b;
                    ans.setText("" + c);
                    n.setText("");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: did you try putting the equals.setOnClickListener block outside the add.setOnClickListener?

Comment: @Nabin Yes.even if i use equals.set......  outside the add.set block and use if else condition to check which operation is to be done,it still dosen't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first line you do:

```
n.setText("");
```

Only after that you read the text with

```
n.getText().toString()
```

Which returns an empty string that is passed to parseFloat().
parseFloat() does not expect an empty string so it throws an exception and your application closes.

So, do not setText("") before you actually read the value you need.

More generally, I would consider saving the current state each time there is a click. You can, for example, enable the equal button only after a number is typed, the operator button clicked and another number is typed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the .java file. Some button code is missing due to lack of space.

```
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (equalcheck == true) {
            textViewresult.setText("");
            equalcheck = false;
        } else {
            textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + "1");
        }
    }
});
two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (equalcheck == true) {
            textViewresult.setText("");
            equalcheck = false;
        } else

            textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + "2");
    }
});


seven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (equalcheck == true) {
            textViewresult.setText("");
            equalcheck = false;
        }
        textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + "7");
    }
});


eight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (equalcheck == true) {
            textViewresult.setText("");
            equalcheck = false;
        }
        textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + "8");

    }
});


nine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (equalcheck == true) {
            textViewresult.setText("");
            equalcheck = false;
        }
        textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + "8");
    }
});

zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //textViewresult.setText("");
        textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + "0");
    }
});


dot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (equalcheck == true) {
            textViewresult.setText("");
            equalcheck = false;
        }
        textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + ".");
    }
});

plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (textViewresult.getText() == "") {

            textViewresult.setText("");
        } else {
            val1 = Double.parseDouble(textViewresult.getText() + "");
            add = true;

            textViewresult.setText(null);
        }
    }
});

minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (textViewresult.getText() == "") {

            textViewresult.setText("");
        } else {
            val1 = Double.parseDouble(textViewresult.getText() + "");
            sub = true;
            textViewresult.setText(null);
        }
    }
});

multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (textViewresult.getText() == "") {

            textViewresult.setText("");
        } else {
            val1 = Double.parseDouble(textViewresult.getText() + "");
            mul = true;
            textViewresult.setText(null);
        }
    }
});
division.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (textViewresult.getText() == "") {

            textViewresult.setText("");
        } else {
            val1 = Double.parseDouble(textViewresult.getText() + "");
            div = true;
            textViewresult.setText(null);
        }
    }
});

equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (textViewresult.getText() == "") {
            textViewresult.setText("");
        } else {
            equalcheck = true;
            val2 = Double.parseDouble(textViewresult.getText() + "");
            if (add == true) {
                textViewresult.setText(val1 + val2 + "");
                add = false;
            }
            if (sub == true) {
                textViewresult.setText(val1 - val2 + "");
                sub = false;
            }
            if (mul == true) {
                textViewresult.setText(val1 * val2 + "");
                mul = false;
            }
            if (div == true) {
                textViewresult.setText(val1 / val2 + "");
                div = false;
            }
        }
    }
});
clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textViewresult.setText("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.rahul.calculator;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero, plus,      minus, multiply, division, equal, dot, clear;
    TextView textViewresult = null;
    double val1, val2;

    boolean add, sub, div, mul;
    boolean equalcheck = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
        two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
        three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_3);
        four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_4);
        five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_5);
        six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_6);
        seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_7);
        eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_8);
        nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_9);
        zero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_0);
        plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);
        minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_minus);
        multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_multiply);
        division = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_divide);
        equal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_equal);
        textViewresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        dot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_dot);
        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_clear);


        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (equalcheck == true) {
                    textViewresult.setText("");
                    equalcheck = false;
                } else {
                    textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + "1");
                }
            }
        });


        two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (equalcheck == true) {
                    textViewresult.setText("");
                    equalcheck = false;
                } else

                    textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + "2");
            }
        });


        three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (equalcheck == true) {
                    textViewresult.setText("");
                    equalcheck = false;
                }
                textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + "3");
            }
        });


        four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (equalcheck == true) {
                    textViewresult.setText("");
                    equalcheck = false;
                }
                textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + "4");
            }
        });


        five.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (equalcheck == true) {
                    textViewresult.setText("");
                    equalcheck = false;
                }
                textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + "5");
            }
        });


        six.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (equalcheck == true) {
                    textViewresult.setText("");
                    equalcheck = false;
                }
                textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + "6");
            }
        });


        seven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (equalcheck == true) {
                    textViewresult.setText("");
                    equalcheck = false;
                }
                textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + "7");
            }
        });


        eight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (equalcheck == true) {
                    textViewresult.setText("");
                    equalcheck = false;
                }
                textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + "8");

            }
        });


        nine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (equalcheck == true) {
                    textViewresult.setText("");
                    equalcheck = false;
                }
                textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + "8");
            }
        });

        zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //textViewresult.setText("");
                textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + "0");
            }
        });


        dot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (equalcheck == true) {
                    textViewresult.setText("");
                    equalcheck = false;
                }
                textViewresult.setText(textViewresult.getText() + ".");
            }
        });

        plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (textViewresult.getText() == "") {

                    textViewresult.setText("");
                } else {
                    val1 = Double.parseDouble(textViewresult.getText() + "");
                    add = true;

                    textViewresult.setText(null);
                }
            }
        });

        minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (textViewresult.getText() == "") {

                    textViewresult.setText("");
                } else {
                    val1 = Double.parseDouble(textViewresult.getText() + "");
                    sub = true;
                    textViewresult.setText(null);
                }
            }
        });

        multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (textViewresult.getText() == "") {

                    textViewresult.setText("");
                } else {
                    val1 = Double.parseDouble(textViewresult.getText() + "");
                    mul = true;
                    textViewresult.setText(null);
                }
            }
        });
        division.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (textViewresult.getText() == "") {

                    textViewresult.setText("");
                } else {
                    val1 = Double.parseDouble(textViewresult.getText() + "");
                    div = true;
                    textViewresult.setText(null);
                }
            }
        });

        equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (textViewresult.getText() == "") {

                    textViewresult.setText("");
                } else {

                    equalcheck = true;
                    val2 = Double.parseDouble(textViewresult.getText() + "");
                    if (add == true) {


                        textViewresult.setText(val1 + val2 + "");
                        add = false;

                    }
                    if (sub == true) {
                        textViewresult.setText(val1 - val2 + "");
                        sub = false;
                    }
                    if (mul == true) {
                        textViewresult.setText(val1 * val2 + "");
                        mul = false;
                    }
                    if (div == true) {
                        textViewresult.setText(val1 / val2 + "");
                        div = false;
                    }

                }

            }

        });
        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textViewresult.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private boolean op=false;
    private double f_value=0;
    private int s_value_index=0;
    private char oper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Buttons and their values

        final TextView show= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        final Button n9= (Button) findViewById(R.id.n9);
        final Button n8= (Button) findViewById(R.id.n8);
        final Button add= (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        final Button clr= (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        final Button dlt= (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
        final Button equal= (Button) findViewById(R.id.equal);

        final View.OnClickListener xal =new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                final int id=v.getId();
                switch (id){
                    case R.id.n9:{
                        show.append("9");
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.n8:{
                        show.append("8");
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.add:{
                        String content1=show.getText().toString();
                        s_value_index=content1.length()+1;
                        f_value= Double.parseDouble(content1);
                        op=true;
                        show.append("+");
                        oper='+';
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.equal:{
                        if(op)
                        {
                            if (oper=='+')
                            {
                                String content= show.getText().toString();
                                String content2=
                               content.substring(s_value_index,content.length());
                                double s_value=Double.parseDouble(content2);
                                s_value+=f_value;
                                show.setText(String.valueOf(s_value));
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        n9.setOnClickListener(xal);
        n8.setOnClickListener(xal);
        add.setOnClickListener(xal);
        equal.setOnClickListener(xal);

        //Clears a single one
        clr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String str;
                str=show.getText().toString();
                int len=str.length();
                if(len>0)
                {
                    str=str.substring(0,len-1);
                    show.setText(str);
                }
            }
        });

        //Deletes the whole
        dlt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String s="";
                show.setText(s.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am here just using two number 8(n8) and 9(n9) and add(+),clear(clr),delete(dlt) buttons. The add will just add numbers using **double type variable** and **clear** would **delete** the last digit entered by user and delete will delete the whole string(all digits or any special symbols) on the screen(for which I am using textView).

Answer (score 0):

```
**

> ***SIMPLE CALCULATOR CODE***

**


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edit;
    Button add, subtract, multiply, divide, equal,clr;
    TextView result;
    String operator;
    float temp1, temp2, sum;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addition);
        subtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subtraction);
        multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiplication);
        divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.division);
        equal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equal);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_input);
        clr = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);

        try {
            //Additon
            add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (temp1 == 0) {
                        temp1 = Float.parseFloat(edit.getText().toString());
                        operator = "+";
                        edit.setText("");
                    } else {

                        edit.setText("");
                    }
                }
            });

            //Division
            divide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (temp1 == 0) {
                        temp1 = Float.parseFloat(edit.getText().toString());
                        operator = "/";

                        edit.setText("");
                    } else {
                        edit.setText("");
                    }
                }
            });

            //Subtract
            subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (temp1 == 0) {
                        temp1 = Float.parseFloat(edit.getText().toString());
                        operator = "-";
                        edit.setText("");

                    } else {

                        edit.setText("");
                    }
                }
            });

            //Multiplication
            multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (temp1 == 0) {
                        temp1 = Float.parseFloat(edit.getText().toString());
                        operator = "*";
                        edit.setText("");
                    } else {
                        edit.setText("");
                    }
                }
            });

            //Clear
            clr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    temp1 = 0;
                    temp2 = 0;
                    edit.setText("");
                    result.setText("");

                }
            });

            //Equal
            equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (temp2 == 0) {
                        temp2 = Float.parseFloat(edit.getText().toString());
                        switch (operator) {
                            case "+":
                                sum = temp1 + temp2;

                                break;
                            case "-":
                                sum = temp1 - temp2;
                                break;
                            case "*":
                                sum = temp1 * temp2;
                                break;
                            case "/":
                                sum = temp1 / temp2;
                                break;

                        }
                        edit.setText(Float.toString(sum));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"RESULT IS DISPLAYED IN EDIT TEXT VIEW :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        result.setText(Float.toString(temp1)+" "+operator+" "+Float.toString(temp2));

                    }

                    temp1 = 0;
                    temp2 = 0;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. This simply gives an example of a working calculator something that we can all find on github. Also you need to explain your answer not just post the code.

Comment: Thanks, to drawing my attention here . Next time i will do that.